# JAppet loading images

Tags: java, static, initialization, java-2d, japplet

I made a game using JFrame, and now I want to deploy it in JApplet, yet I get the following exception:

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

As much as Google told me it is caused by static initializers, and the only thing I do in my static initialization blocks is call to the following function:

```
public static BufferedImage[] loadAnimation (String fileName, int subimagewidth, int subimageheight, int pixelsbetweensprites) {


    BufferedImage spr = null;
    BufferedImage[] animation;

    int x, y;           //amount of images in each direction

    try {
        Object ob = new Object();
        spr = ImageIO.read(ob.getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.exit(0);
        Logger.getLogger(AnimationLoader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    x = spr.getWidth() / subimagewidth;
    y = spr.getHeight() / subimageheight;

    animation = new BufferedImage[x*y];

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            animation[j*x+i] = spr.getSubimage(i*(subimagewidth + pixelsbetweensprites), j*(subimageheight+pixelsbetweensprites), subimagewidth, subimageheight);
        }
    }

    return animation;

}
```

Is this problem occurs because it is JApplet, or because it is unsigned?
How to fix it (preferably without spending money on signature)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
Object ob = new Object();
spr = ImageIO.read(ob.getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName));
```

You probably want to load the image from the same location your code originates from (e.g. a jar file). Instead you ask `java.lang.Object.class` to give back the stream of the image which is probably not you want (this would search the `filename` resource in the internal libraries of the JRE or JDK - more specifically in the `rt.jar` file).

If indeed you want to load the image from the same jar your class files originates from, you should acquire the stream like this:

```
InputStream in = YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream(filename);
```

You should pass this `InputStream` to your `loadAnimation()` method, or pass both the `Class` along with the file name to be used to get the stream of the image.

Comment: Thanks it fixed the problem. Strange though that simply using Object worked with JFrame but not with JApplet.